# Merge in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

What is difference between

pd.merge(staff_df, student_df, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)

and

pd.merge(staff_df, student_df, how='left', left_on='Name', right_on='Name')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First merge by indexes in both `DataFrames` by left join:

```
pd.merge(staff_df, student_df, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

And second and simplify third left join by column `Name` in both `DataFrames`:

```
pd.merge(staff_df, student_df, how='left', left_on='Name', right_on='Name')
pd.merge(staff_df, student_df, how='left', on='Name')
```

**Samples**:

```
staff_df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':list('abb'),
                   'B':[4,5,3],
                   'C':list('asd')}, index=list('ded'))

print (staff_df)
   B  C Name
d  4  a    a
e  5  s    b
d  3  d    b

student_df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':list('abc'),
                   'A':[4,5,3],
                   'D':list('asd')}, index=list('dkl'))

print (student_df)
   A  D Name
d  4  a    a
k  5  s    b
l  3  d    c
```

---

```
df = pd.merge(staff_df, student_df, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
print (df)
   B  C Name_x    A    D Name_y
d  4  a      a  4.0    a      a
d  3  d      b  4.0    a      a
e  5  s      b  NaN  NaN    NaN

df = pd.merge(staff_df, student_df, how='left', on='Name')
print (df)
   B  C Name  A  D
0  4  a    a  4  a
1  5  s    b  5  s
2  3  d    b  5  s
```

Answer (score 0):

If **student_df** is

```
>>> student_df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['x','y','z'], 'id': [1, 2, 3]})
>>> student_df

    id name
0   1    x
1   2    y
2   3    z
```

And **staff_df** is something like

```
>>> staff_df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a','b','z'], 'id': [34, 35, 36]})
>>> staff_df

    id name
0   34    a
1   35    b
2   36    z
```

*left_index=True, right_index=True* will merge 0th row of **student_df** with 0th row **staff_df**. For example this will be output of that

```
     id_x name_x  id_y name_y
0     1      x    34      a
1     2      y    35      b
2     3      z    36      z
```

It can also be that you're using index from `left dataframe` and refrencing to `id` of right dataframe

```
>>> pd.merge(student_df, staff_df, how='left',right_index=True,left_on='id')
   id_x name_x  id_y name_y
0     1      x  35.0      b
1     2      y  36.0      z
2     3      z   NaN    NaN
```

But when you use `on` in both right and left, then those column values for rows are matched and merged on those,(quite to similar to using join columns).